# Python: How to concatenate adjacent strings in list having combined length less than threshold?

Tags: python, string-concatenation

I would like to merge/concatenate adjacent strings in a list whose combined length is below a threshold. The concatenated string should have a single space separating the individual strings.

For example, if the list contains the following strings:

```
list = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'sample', 'example']
```

and the threshold is 10, then the list should be modified to:

```
list = ['This is a', 'sample', 'example']
```

**Edit:** I am using a for loop comparing adjacent strings.

```
for i in range(1, len(list)):
    if len(list[i]) + len(list[i-1]) < 10:
        list[i-1] = list[i-1]+' '+list[i]
        del list[i]
```

but this gives `IndexError: list index out of range` because the loop counter has been initialized to the initial `len(list)`.

Comment: what is problem to do it?

Comment: I have edited the question to include where I got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
import textwrap

sample = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'sample', 'example', 'stringbiggerthan10', 'otherstring']

sample_join = " ".join(sample)

textwrap.wrap(sample_join, width=10, break_long_words=False)

['This is a', 'sample', 'example', 'stringbiggerthan10', 'otherstring']
```

Comment: The limitation of this approach is that if a string is 10 chars or more, it will be broken down into segments, which I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

One (a bit lazy) way to do this is using the [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap) module from the standard library:

```
>> import textwrap
>> textwrap.wrap('This is a sample example', width=10)
['This is a', 'sample', 'example']
```

(If your text is already split into words, you'll have to join it back first, which is a bit wasteful, but still works.)

Comment: The limitation of this approach is that if a string is 10 chars or more, it will be broken down into segments, which I don't want.